# How to save the SharePoint File Upload Link in C# MVC Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, sharepoint, file-upload

I am using the following code to upload files to SharePoint:

```
        var securePassword = new SecureString();

        foreach (var c in "NotMyPWD123")
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }

        var ctx = new ClientContext("https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/ProjectRoom")
        {
            Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username@company.com", securePassword)
        };

        using (var target = new MemoryStream())
        {
            vm.UploadedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(target);

            target.Position = 0;

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, $"/sites/ProjectRoom/Project Room Test/{vm.UploadedFile.FileName}", target, true);
        }
```

My question is: Is it possible to get/save the link/URL of the file that was uploaded to SharePoint? That way a user can click the link in the future and open the file.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following two lines of code in between `target.Position = 0;` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client`...:

```
var serverRelativeUrl = $"/sites/ProjectRoom/Project Room Test/{vm.UploadedFile.FileName}";

var absoluteUrl = new Uri(ctx.Url).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + serverRelativeUrl;
```